# dpkg --list not showing installed kernel version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, eudyptula-challenge

I am running ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.13

I was following eudyptula challenge which asked me to download kernel source from linus's git and build,install, which I did and now I have two kernels, 3.13 and 3.15.

I wanted to verify the installation and read on some website that dpkg --list | grep linux-image would give me list of all installed kernels but I get only 3.13.

I currently booted 3.15

terminal outputs below:

```
ashish@ashish-PC:~$ uname -r
3.15.0-07913-g64b2d1f

ashish@ashish-PC:~$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                         3.13.0-24.46                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                   3.13.0-24.46                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.24.28                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed from source not creating a .deb package `dpkg --list` won't show you because it didn't install it and knows nothing about it.

Answer (score 1):

check your `/boot` directory:

```
$ ll /boot/
total 30M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 773K avr 10  2012 abi-3.2.0-23-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 137K avr 10  2012 config-3.2.0-23-generic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  12K déc  3  2013 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21M déc 12 18:16 initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 2,8M avr 10  2012 System.map-3.2.0-23-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4,8M mai 20  2012 vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
```

Your kernel are the `vmlinuz*` files.